# Blackhole and light

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, newtonian-gravity, photons

I was talking with my friend about blackholes and I asked him "Why blackhole 'sucks' the photons?"

He had no deeper understanding so he answered that "I dont know, may the light is affected, because blackhole affects the volume of space (dont know better translation)", so I am asking you:

1. Is that some gravitational coexistence? (but photon has no mass)
2. Is the photon directly "sucked" into blackhole?
3. Can we measure mass of blackhole?

Have a nice day!

Comment: *"that the mass is rounded to infinity in every context of blackhole"*...whereever you have seen that, that is just wrong. Also, duplicate of [What happens to light that falls into a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26337/50583)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I edited to not share heresy, but my question is "why the photon is affected"

Comment: That would be [How is light affected by gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34352/50583) and [How can gravity affect light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/50583)